# Allow users to access specified IPs only

Tags: ssh, firewall, iptables

I have a computer that offers both a VPN and a SSH server running three (separated) VPN networks.

All users log into the server via ssh. However, I want that only certain users can communicate to certain IPs in the VPN networks.

For example:

user peter -> **only** 10.100.0.4

user chris -> **only** 10.100.0.5

user john -> **only** 10.200.0.*

user nick -> **all** IPs (10.100.0.*, 10.200.0.*, the internet itself)

Is this possible using ufw or iptables? I have found no instructions how to do this user-specifically.

edit: To be more precise: I want to restrict the connectivity of the users itself (even if they are sitting at the PC and log in directly), so I doubt this is a problem that can be addressed (only) by sshd.

tags: reinserted iptables, as ssh alone is not correct...

Comment: Just being friendly in advanced...have you tried `man sshd` ?

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to restrict ssh itself. I want to restrict the connectivity of certain users. In other words: Even if they are sitting at the PC and logging in directly, they should not be able to access other IPs than those specified ones. So I doubt that this is a problem of sshd. (added this information to the question itself to clarify things).

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe OpenLDAP + iptables approach is festive to your situation? http://mayank03.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/install-and-configure-openldap/ and http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html

Comment: I have read both of the articles you have mentioned, but I cannot find something that look familiar with my situation. Why do I need OpenLDAP? How can I benefit from using it concerning iptables?